# object object is displaying in input field while using emoji-mart this is my code anyone can tell my mistake

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {Picker} from "emoji-mart"

function Emoji() {
    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

    const text = '';

    const addEmoji = (e) => {
        let emoji = e.native;
        setInput({
            key: 'text',
            text: input.text + emoji});
         console.log("typed", input )
    }

    const sendMessage = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("final",input)

        setInput('')
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <input type='text' value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}/>
                <button onClick={sendMessage} type="submit">send</button>
            </form>
            <span><Picker set='apple' value={input} onSelect={addEmoji}/></span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Emoji
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the input field in 2 different ways, `<input />'s onChange` sets a text, and in `addEmoji` you are setting an object, you should either maintain different state for each callbacks, or have the object for input and set the values appropriately.

```js
const addEmoji = (e) => {
  let emoji = e.native;
   setInput({
     key: 'text',
     text: input.text + emoji
  });
}
```

And I'm not sure where the `input.text` is coming from, though it wasn't set in `useState()`.

Currently, you are passing an empty string as the initial value to the input state, it should be an object

```
[input, setInput] = useState({})

<input onChange={e => { 
   setInput(prevState => {...prevState, {key: 'text', text: e.target.value}})
  } 
/>
```

Once the object set properly, you would be able to read the text property while calling addEmoji, and in addEmoji you need to update the code to set the proper keys, like I've shown above in the `onChange` callback.

```js
const addEmoji = (e) => {
  const emoji = e.native;
  setInput(prevState => {...prevState, {
    text: input.text + emoji
  });
}
```